# How do you randomly assign the value of a variable, to another variable in python?

Tags: python

This is wrecking my brain, and I have searched everywhere to no avail. Here is an example:

```
masNoun = ["Mann", "Junge"]
femNoun = ["Frau"]
neuNoun = ["Madchen", "Kind"]
masArt = ["ein"]
femArt = ["eine"]
firstProSing = ["Ich"]
seconProSing = ["du"]
thirdProSing = ["Er", "Sie"]
firstVerb = ["bin"]
seconVerb = ["bist"]
thirdVerb = ["ist"]

subject = firstProSing or seconProSing or thirdProSing
verb = firstVerb or seconVerb or thirdVerb
object1 = masArt or femArt
object2 = masNoun or femNoun
```

Output: Output seems to always be the first variable. I tried using the random module as follows:

```
object1 = random.choice(masNoun or femNoun)
```

The result is still the same, with the first variable being the outputted choice.
The "or" function seems to not work for my example. I am stumped at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please explain what you want the result to be. I don't know why you would think that `or` would do anything randomly.

Comment: I updated the code above, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The `or` keyword in Python functions as a boolean operator - it will evaluate an expression to `True` or `False` if the operands are boolean.

In this case, the operands are not boolean values, so the `or` operator will return whichever operand evaluates to `True`. Remember, the `or` operator works in [short-circuit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) fashion.

For example:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = 3
>>> a or b
2
>>> b or a
3
```

To me, it looks like you want the variable to take a random value from a given list of possible values.

In that case, what you want is something along these lines:

```
import random

subjects = ['Ich', 'du', 'er', 'sie']

subject = random.choice(subjects)
```

EDIT: Per the comment, to do this with multiple lists of variables, instead of one combined list, you can do the following:

```
import random

firstProSing = ["Ich"]
secondProSing = ["du"]
thirdProSing = ["Er", "Sie"]

subject = random.choice(firstProSing + secondProSing + thirdProSing)
```

The `+` operator will take lists and combine them, so this code is the equivalent of:

```
subjects = firstProSing + secondProSing + thirdProSing
# Comment: Here the content of subjects is ['Ich', 'du', 'Er', 'Sie']
subject = random.choice(subjects)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I do this with multiple variables instead of the one? For instance:

variable1 = ['Ich', 'du', 'er']
variable2 = ['Mann', 'Frau']

variable3 = random.choice(variable1 or variable2)

Comment: Cool, I will try that.

Comment: Works! Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: `or` does not evaluate *to* True or False; it evaluates to either its first or second argument depending on the truth value of the first argument.

Comment: Good point, I've updated my answer to address this. Please feel free to edit with any corrections!

Answer (score 0):

'Or' statement is not the way. It's a boolean, not a random choice. Random choice can be done like this:

```
import random

subjects = ["Ich", "du", "Er", "Sie"]
verbs = ["bin", "bist", "ist"]
objects1 = ["ein","eine"]
objects2 = ["Mann", "Junge","Frau"]

subject = random.choice(subjects)
verb = random.choice(verbs)
object1 = random.choice(objects1)
object2 = random.choice(objects2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
in OR clause if leftmost condition is True python will not look further

firstProSing = ["Ich"]
seconProSing = ["du"]
thirdProSing = ["Er", "Sie"]

subject = firstProSing or seconProSing or thirdProSing

print(firstProSing)

['Ich']

# here the first value is empty or False, python looks
# right and finds that seconProSing is True so its value 'du' is chosen

subject = "" or seconProSing or thirdProSing

print(subject)

['du']
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory to your answer.